# ¿How can I get a posterior distribution about the uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayesian

[image: Image of the problem in spanish]
I need to get the posterior distribution for theta parameter:
The translate of the image:
let $p(x|\theta)=unif(x|0,\theta)$ with unknown theta and a priori distribution on theta given by:

$p_1(\theta)=2(\theta-1)$.

I have tried it but I can't find the correct answer because when I integrate the posterior distribution that I obtain, does not give me 1.
Thanks.

EDIT: I tried this:
with the Bayes' rule:
$$\begin{align}p_2(\theta\mid x)&=\dfrac{p_1(\theta)~p(x\mid\theta)}{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R p_1(\tau)~p(x\mid\tau)~\mathrm d \tau}\end{align}$$

where $$p(x|\theta) = L(\theta|x_{1},...,x_{n})$$
and then  $$L(\theta|x_{1},...,x_{n})=\frac{1}{\theta^{n}}$$

therefore
$$p_2(\theta\mid x)=\frac{ 2(\theta-1)\theta^{-n} } {\int_{1}^{2}
{2(\tau-1)\tau^{-n}} d\tau} $$

but when I integrate $p_{2}(\theta|x)$ between 1 and 2 the result is different  one

Comment: You should really show what you obtained, and how you obtained it, so we can comment on what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I hadn't seen this comment before, I'll do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use Bayes' Rule.

$$\begin{align}p_2(\theta\mid x)&=\dfrac{p_1(\theta)~p(x\mid\theta)}{\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R p_1(\tau)~p(x\mid\tau)~\mathrm d \tau}\end{align}$$

Where $$\begin{align}p(x\mid\theta)&=\theta^{-1}~\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\theta],\theta\in[1;2]}\\[2ex]p_1(\theta)&=2(\theta-1)~\mathbf 1_{\theta\in[1;2]} \end{align}$$

So...

$$\begin{align}p_2(\theta\mid x)&=\dfrac{(1-1/\theta)~\mathbf 1_{\theta\in[1;2],x\in[0;\theta]}}{\int_1^2 (1-1/\tau)~\mathrm d \tau}\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: But in the Bayes' rule *p(x|theta)* is equal to likelihood because it use the sample information  and then *p(x|theta)* within the formula it will be *p(X|theta)=L(theta|X)* where X=x_{1},x_{2},....,x_{n} ?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  And, so?

Comment: The likelihood it would be $$\theta^{-n}$$ instead $\theta^{-1}$ and then $$p(x|\theta)=\theta^{-n}$$ or am I making a mistake?